# Freemarker 'Collection.contains' functionality

Tags: java, collections, contains, freemarker

From my java code I'm returning a *Set<String>*. The view needs to check if the Set contains a specific string.. I can't find any docs on how Freemarker can handle this.
Any idea?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `seq_contains`. You need FreeMarker 2.3.1

```
${x?seq_contains("blue")?string("yes", "no")}
```

This will output **yes** if the sequence contains "blue".

And from the comments, if you want this in an if statement

```
<#if x?seq_contains("myString")>
```

Here is the doco about it [Built-ins for sequences](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_seq_contains)

Comment: I think the answer could be corrected to have `<#if mySet?seq_contains("myString")>` because there was not specified that printing a string is required

Also just `<#if x.contains("myString")>` should work

Comment: I've added the if example. The point of the first example is to make it clear what `seq_contains` does, I wasn't trying to show all the various statements in which you can use it.